# Expectation of a function using beta distribution or binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, binomial-distribution

Let $X \sim B\bigg(2,\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)$. Then $E\bigg(\dfrac{2}{1+X}\bigg) =$

$(a) = \dfrac{7}{6}$

$(b) = 1$

$(c) = \dfrac{6}{7}$

$(d) = \dfrac{2}{5}$

In this question its not specified whether $X$ follows Beta distribution or Binomial distribution. Now if i use binomial distribution i get answer $\dfrac{7}{6}$. If i use Beta i get $\dfrac{2}{5}$. Which one to use?

Comment: @Clarinetist Can you do this?

Comment: The problem is only notation... In general for Beta distribution use $\beta$ and for Binomial distribution use $\text{Bin}$

Comment: Speculating which distribution to use when the notation is not clear from context is probably a waste of time.

Comment: @StubbornAtom its a question from my previous years. May be they did it on purpose to waste student time or may b something is missing.

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo So using both the distributions i get two options. I dont believe its a special case or just a coincidence. I am very new in probability you can correct me if my intuition is wrong somewhere.

Comment: @MichaelHardy no i just edited that part.

Comment: Your answer for binomial seems correct; almost trivial to get. Not so sure about your answer for beta. Please check that one. Simulation in R statistical software: `x = rbeta(10^6, 2, 1/2);  mean(2/(1+x))` returns $1.130618 \ne 0.4$ -- or even close. Also, for beta answ should be more than 1 because denom always < 2. // I'm betting on binomial.